# How to get Public-ip Address client-side in React which is compatible with internet Explorer(11)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ip, ipv4

My application is working in google chrome.but after getting client side ip using library 'public-ip'. It has stop working in internet explorer(11). Any one have solution for that?.

Comment: "It has stop working in internet explorer(11)" -- Does it work in other browser? Is there any error message in IE11 console? Any screenshot on how it "stop working"?

Answer (score -1):

'public-ip' is for node js (server) not for client side.

To get public IP,

1. Make your own server like node js and use 'public-ip', then provide REST API for getting IP.
2. Just use existing API (https://jsonip.com/) and it will return client's IP. To avoid cross domain problem, you can also use jsonp

Comment: Due to some reason, I cannot do this on server. I need a way to get client IP from the client-side itself.
Can the existing API (https://jsonip.com/) be used on the client-side?